# Embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot Web application does not start with module-info

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-module

I would like to learn some new stuff with java 9+ like modules.
So I created a spring boot application with `spring-boot-starter-web` and `module-info.java`:

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;

    exports com.example.demo;
    opens com.example.demo;
}
```

I used
-> *Java 15.0.2*
-> *Spring Boot 2.4.3*
-> *IntelliJ IDE 2020.3*
-> *Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS*

---

To run the application I use a run button(green arrow) in IntelliJ - default run without any additional params. And the problem is that when I try to run the application, the embedded tomcat server does not start.
**Output with module-info.java**

```
2021-03-12 08:57:12.182  INFO 4843 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 15.0.2 on vagrant-VirtualBox with PID 4843 
2021-03-12 08:57:12.184  INFO 4843 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-12 08:57:13.081  INFO 4843 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.511 seconds (JVM running for 3.418)
```

But, when I remove `module-info.java`, everything is ok, and the tomcat server started.
**Output without module-info.java**

```
2021-03-12 09:01:49.627  INFO 4928 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 15.0.2 on vagrant-VirtualBox with PID 4928 
2021-03-12 09:01:49.633  INFO 4928 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-12 09:01:50.897  INFO 4928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-03-12 09:01:50.912  INFO 4928 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-12 09:01:50.912  INFO 4928 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-03-12 09:01:50.958  INFO 4928 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-12 09:01:50.958  INFO 4928 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1188 ms
2021-03-12 09:01:51.179  INFO 4928 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-03-12 09:01:51.320  INFO 4928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-03-12 09:01:51.329  INFO 4928 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.271 seconds (JVM running for 3.774)
```

I'm wondering the difference between outputs. When I use `module-info.java` Tomcat doesn't run because it is beyond my module?

What can I do to run app?

How do you think, is it make sense to use java modules with Spring Boot?
Why?
Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;` in *modules-info.java* to include `org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.class`, see [this article](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/spring-boot-autoconfiguration/#finding-tomcat) for details on how Spring boot start the tomcat server.